# Can someone create the "planetside-2" tag?

Tags: support, tags

I'm playing the ps 2 beta and noticed that there is a lot of stuff that is poorly or not at all documented/explained. It's also very hard to search for this information since it's mostly passed around from player to player *(or contained in non-searchable 4chan images)*. I'd love to post some self-answered questions after I found something out to help others. Also I'd love the ability to ask in case I can't find an answer after a while.

I can't do so yet since the tag does not exist and I don't have 300 rep here to create it.

Can someone create the [planetside-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planetside-2) tag please? Thank you.

Comment: We usually don't create tags (or allow questions) for games that are not widely available.  Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: Oh ok. I searched a bit around and figured it's fine to ask beta questions as long as they are answerable (no guessing around). If it's too early yet, thats certainly ok. Someone should update the FAQ in this case though, since it's not explicitely mentioned.

Comment: if you ask a question and leave it as untagged we can go in and tag it for you.  Usually there's no reason to create a tag unless there's a question about it, but new users can't create new tags, a catch-22.

Comment: You can't ask a question without a tag of any sort @yx. Standard advice is to use a tag of last resort such as an appropriate platform or genre tag, and then flag for moderator attention, or just ask in [chat] for a user with sufficient reputation to retag it. It happens pretty quickly either way in most cases.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I meant that they should use the [tag:untagged] tag, which makes it easier to spot, but yea, that works too

Comment: @yx. Didn't know users could use the untagged tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no special process in creating a tag. To create a tag you simply attach it to a question.

If you don't have enough reputation to create a tag you will simply have to rely on more experienced users to edit it in for you.